# ZPL Nested Start and End Tags

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii

Can we use nested start and end tag for ZPL as per below structure?
^XA
...
^XA
...
^XZ
...
^XZ
My use case is if you want to apply some property at document level (for all the pages) you can include that in the upper structure instead of including that in each start and end tag.
I have tried this and its giving me correct output.
please suggest me is this correct way to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point this will not give you the output you expect.  The first ^XZ should be denoting the end of the print job and causing the label to print.  The second ^XZ is likely being ignored.

The way you would want to set this up is:

```
^XA
...properties, print speed darkness, etc
...makes setting changes but does not print a label
^XZ
...
^XA
...label code
^XZ
```